# how to convert string in to json array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**image name**

```
    021D3BB2995711E7BFD706E21CB7534C---FEATURED_IMAGE__images.jpg
```

**this image name convert into json aray and output like this **

> [“021D3BB2995711E7BFD706E21CB7534C---FEATURED_IMAGE__images.jpg”]

Comment: Try this `var str =  '021D3BB2995711E7BFD706E21CB7534C---FEATURED_IMAGE__images.jpg';
var arr = [str]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not get your question 100%, but if you have a `String` and want it to be in an array, you can use the `.push()` method.

```
var myString = 'hello';
console.log(myString); // hello

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(myString);
console.log(myArray); // ['hello']
myArray = JSON.stringify(myArray);
console.log(myArray); // "["hello"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
str='021D3BB2995711E7BFD706E21CB7534C---FEATURED_IMAGE__images.jpg';
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + str + ']');
```

Comment: Best not to assume OP is using jQuery. The question is tagged Javascript and Angular, not jQuery.